# How to add element to TreeView Child and store it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm actually write a code to add some values in TreeView, check:

```
       TreeViewItem treeItem = null;

        treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
        treeItem.Header = "Italia";

        treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Serie A" });
        treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Serie B" });

        nation_team.Items.Add(treeItem); //add all items on the control..
```

So the result in WPF is this:

```
Italia
      Serie A
      Serie B
```

I'm wondering now, how to add value to Serie A and B, in particular I'm waiting this result:

```
Italia
      Serie A
          Inter
          Milan
      Serie B
          Avellino
          Salerno
```

How I can achieve this result?
PS: How to store all values of TreeView? In particular Save all child of Italia and all child of Serie A? Should I create a class like this:

```
public TreeClass
{
    string nations {get;set;} //Italia and so on..
    string championships {get; set;}  //Serie A and Serie B..
    string teams {get; set;} //Inter, Milan, Avellino, Salerno...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

XAML Method:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Italia">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Serie A">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Milan" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Inter" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Serie B">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Avellino" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Salerno" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Code Behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    InitTreeView();
}

private void InitTreeView()
{
    TreeViewItem rootNode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Italia" };

    rootNode.Items.Add(GetSeriesA());
    rootNode.Items.Add(GetSeriesB());

    treeView.Items.Add(rootNode);
}

private TreeViewItem GetSeriesA()
{
    TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem() {Header = "Series A"};
    item.Header = "Series A";
    item.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem(){Header = "Inter"});
    item.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem(){Header = "Milan"});
    return item;
}

private TreeViewItem GetSeriesB()
{
    TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Series B" };

    item.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem(){Header = "Avellino"});
    item.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem(){Header = "Salerno"});
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Could you poste an example behind code? Because my is an example, I know how to do this in XAML.. My data is dynamic so I don't know the values of the Database.

Comment: Working on it now one sec :)

Comment: Added! Looks very similar to looedcode's answer, just structured a bit different.

Comment: Ok is nice solution, but how I said, I don't how many values "root" there's in the DB. In my example there's one Nation "Italia" that's have two championships, each championships have two teams. 
But I need a general structure like Nations -> Championships -> Teams. Should I must write a class like my question topic? check please.

Comment: Yes, in this case I would pull the data from the DB, construct your class and them bind it to your TreeView using "ItemsSource" to point to the collection.

Comment: Good. Thanks for the support :D

Answer (score 0):

TreeViewItem has the Items property to hold child item.

```
var item1 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Serie A" });
item1.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Inter" } );
item1.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Milan" } );
var item2 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Serie B" });
item2.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Avellino" } );
item2.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Salerno" } );
treeItem.Items.Add(item1);
treeItem.Items.Add(item2);
```

Typically, you would want to load this data recursively from some form defined configuration XML or other data.

Comment: I didn't write the whole code, you still have to add the item1 and item2 inside the treeItem.Items.Add(item1); treeItem.Items.Add(item2);